# set a data range in column 0 of an mts in Rstudio

Tags: r, time-series

I am new in Rstudio having a question. I have a created a multivariate ts using 3 ts of the same sample period, using the ts.union() function. So when I open this mts object I have in column 0 the number of the observations and my variables in the following columns. I wonder if it's possible to assign quarterly time periods in column 0 instead of having the number of the obs. This will give me a perfect look of my data set. To be more specific my quarterly range is 1971:Q1 up to 2014:Q3. Thank you very much.

Comment: In `R` there is no column zero, `R` is one-based. Can you please revise your question and include **in the question** the output of `dput(your_mts)`?

Comment: Please review [mcve] and, in particular, provide test data in an easily reproduced form and show your code.  Construct a minimal example if your actual data is large.

Comment: @Rui Barradas Actually I am using Rstudio if that makes a difference. There is a column 0 when I open the mts object. Dim = c(166L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Gap", "Inflation", "FFR", "FFRlag"
)), .Tsp = c(1971.25, 2012.5, 4), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"
))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If freq=4 is used it will assume it is a quarterly series:

```
n <- 4 * (2014 - 1971 + 1)  # number of rows
ts(cbind(1:n, 1:n), start = 1971, freq = 4)
##         Series 1 Series 2
## 1971 Q1        1        1
## 1971 Q2        2        2
## 1971 Q3        3        3
## 1971 Q4        4        4
## 1972 Q1        5        5
## ...snip...
```

Comment: When I type `list(logdata)` i can see in the console the quarterly date in the first column and my variables in the following columns, but when I open (left double-click) the mts object, I get the number of the obs in column 0. Thats what I see in my Rstudio.